# Are transfinite numbers like aleph nought, continuum etc. a set itself?

Tags: set-theory

Are transfinite numbers like aleph nought, continuum etc.  a set itself ?

Comment: Each one is. The collection of all transfinite numbers is not.

Comment: @Arthur:  In case of finite set, we say that to  compare or to measure size of a set i.e which one is larger or smaller, the term cardinal number has been introduced and thus cardinality comes out to be   a number. However In case of infinite set, the term transfinite numbers are adapted in the same sense, may not be a number but intuition was same but its amazing that every thing in set theory can be viewed as a set. In context of Number theory, Is aleph nought and continuum itself are set or a number?

Comment: @Andres E.Caicedo,  In context of Number theory, Is aleph nought and continuum itself are set or a number?

Comment: They are sets. We also call them numbers. Of course, these "numbers" are not natural numbers, or real numbers, or anything like that. Entirely different creatures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, in the context of set theory, almost anything is a set. $\aleph_0$ is a set (as is any other cardinal). Any function is also a set.

$\Bbb R$ is a set, either just of points, but also the topological space, the metric space, the group, the field, the $\Bbb Q$-vector space, and any other interpretation, common or uncommon, with or without ordering, of $\Bbb R$, regardless of whether you like to define it from Dedekind cuts, Cauchy sequences, or any other way.

However, there are things that are not sets, even though they intuitively look like collections of things. They are called proper classes (sets can also be classes, but they are not proper). Which ones they are depend on your specific axioms, but in the standard set theory called $ZF$, some proper classes include the class of all sets, the class of all cardinals, or something like the class of all topological spaces (which, together with all possible continuous functions between them become the *category* of topological spaces).

Comment: What are the elements of $\aleph_0$ then, the natural numbers?

Comment: @Masacrosso Yes, that's what they are.